# PHP Reflection with kayako api

Tags: php, reflection

I am trying to access a private property from a kayako ticket object that is returned and reflection seems the way to go to do this. Here I tried what seems to be the proper method but I get nothing returned and since it's private i cant do it the normal easy way for getting a property's value. please assist.

```
/* no output */
public function load_ticket($id) {
    $content = kyTicket::get($id);
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($content);

    $posts = $reflect->getProperty('posts');
    $posts->setAccessible(true);
    print_r($posts->getValue(new kyTicket));


/* fatal error - see below */
public function load_ticket($id) {
    $content = kyTicket::get($id);
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($content);

    $posts = $reflect->getProperty('posts')->getValue();
    print_r($posts);
```

[29-Sep-2014 17:32:13] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Cannot access non-public member kyTicket::posts' in /var/www/html/site/public_html/inc/QA/External/kayako.class.php:49

Please point me in the right direction or let me know how to get the following info from:

```
kyTicket Object
(
    [id:protected] => 6
    [flag_type:protected] => 5
    [display_id:protected] => 1234
    [department_id:protected] => 3
    [status_id:protected] => 3
    [priority_id:protected] => 6
    [type_id:protected] => 1
    [user_id:protected] => 202
    [user_organization_name:protected] =>
    [posts:kyTicket:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => kyTicketPost Object
                (
                    [id:protected] => 6
                    [ticket_id:protected] => 6
                    [dateline:protected] => 1407409550
                    [user_id:protected] => 202
                    [full_name:protected] => Agent
                    [email:protected] => email@gmail.com
                    [email_to:protected] =>
                    [ip_address:protected] => 1.2.3.4
                    [has_attachments:protected] =>
                    [creator:protected] => 2
                    [is_third_party:protected] =>
                    [is_html:protected] =>
                    [is_emailed:protected] =>
                    [staff_id:protected] =>
                    [is_survey_comment:protected] =>
                    [contents:protected] => Chat ID: 1234
email contents here
```

I am trying to get posts->[0]->contents

Thanks again!

Comment: `print_r($posts->getValue($content));`

Comment: I knew it was something simple I was missing i tried $posts->getValue(new kyTicket);

Comment: What's wrong with `$content->getPosts()`?